# Data Array Always Process to String not Array With Angular.fromJson

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, angularjs-scope, angularjs-http

I have a problem, I did set field form to array. Example : Field `dfp_interest` in response is []. So, i must set my data to array right ? I did and success in console.log. Result like --> `["5","6"]` but when I process in `angular.fromJson` and i send with `$http`, my params dfp_interest is string not array. Am I wrong ? Give me solution or i do some mistakes ?

**This is my process to send params in API**

```
var a = angular.fromJson({
            "data" : "{\"username\": \"newshubid\", \"data\":{\"_id\": \""+ $scope.id +"\",\"label\": \""+ $scope.label +"\",\"active\": \""+ $scope.active +"\",\"parent_id\": \""+ $scope.parent_id +"\",\"level\": \""+ $scope.level +"\",\"meta_title\": \""+ $scope.meta_title +"\",\"meta_description\": \""+ $scope.meta_description +"\", \"meta_keyword\": \""+ $scope.meta_keyword +"\", \"dfp_interest\": \""+ $scope.tes +"\"}}"
        });

        var param = $.param(a);

        HttpService("POST", url, param, function(response){
            alert(response.message);
        });
```

**This is example my data array for `dfp_interest`**

```
$scope.tes = [5, 6];

$scope.testarray = $scope.tes.join("");
```

Comment: You don't understand what JSON is. What you pass into `angular.fromJson` is not a JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`angular.fromJson` accepts a string argument, with that said your code should be;

```
var data = {username: 'newshubid', 
            data: { id: $scope.id, 
                    label: $scope.label, 
                    active: $scope.active,
                    parent_id: $scope.parent_id,
                    level: $scope.level,
                    meta_title: $scope.meta_title,
                    meta_description: $scope.meta_description,
                    meta_keyword: $scope.meta_keyword,
                    dfp_interest: $scope.tes }
           };

    var a = angular.fromJson(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: Variables interpolation `$scope.id`, etc.

Comment: But "id" and $scope.id no need ("") ?

Comment: @userpr `JSON.stringify` will do that for you

Comment: the console.log is object not string

Comment: So, formData in xhr is object Object and cant process to API

Comment: Just less "_id" and my xhr not working. Im sorry , i do somemistake and
inaccurate. thanks for helping me sir @Azola